# React native webview android "choose and action" is not opening

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

I am using [react-native-webview](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview). I would like choose camera when i click choose file button but directs me directly to the file directory, so "choose and action" popup isn't opening on android. Ios working well.   how can i fix this?

Webview Code;

```
 <WebView 
     style={{width:"100%", flex:1}}
     source={{html: HTML}}
  />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> ReactNative's WebView on Android does not support file input. This
> library adds in an  that does support file input, as
> well adding support for a number of other missing pieces, listed
> below.

try [react-native-webview-file-upload-android](https://github.com/Oblongmana/react-native-webview-file-upload-android)

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import { WebView, View, Platform } from 'react-native';
import AndroidWebView from 'react-native-webview-file-upload-android';

 <View style={{flex:1}}>
        {Platform.select({
              android:  () => <AndroidWebView
                                source={{ uri: 'https://mobilehtml5.org/ts/?id=23' }}
                              />,
              ios:      () => <WebView
                                source={{ uri: 'https://mobilehtml5.org/ts/?id=23' }}
                              />
        })()}
      </View>
```

Comment: This repo DEPRECATED and said "Please use https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview". Cant i solve this issue on react-native-webview ?